# VS2010 Installations. I want it all. What should I install?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If I install

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (x86) - DVD (English)

Are the following seperate MSDN installs already included?

Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 (x86) - DVD (English) 
Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (x86 and x64) - DVD (English) 
en_visual_studio_2010_tools_for_the_office_system_4.0_runtime_x86_510110.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 (x86) - DVD (English) - **Yes** (bundled within the devenv IDE, not as a separate program)
- Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (x86 and x64) - DVD (English) - **No**
- en_visual_studio_2010_tools_for_the_office_system_4.0_runtime_x86_510110.exe - **Yes**

Comment: Team Explorer Everywhere is only necessary if you plan to use that on another platform without Visual Studio. Check out the details on this download link, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AF1F5168-C0F7-47C6-BE7A-2A83A6C02E57&displaylang=en